# Is there is any way to create a function which accept any datatype value and print that value?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I want to write a single function which accepts two values of different data types and prints those two values using a function. Is there any way to do so without modifying the below code, except the function parameters?

Here is my C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printValues( ______________ )
{
    cout << val1 << " " << val2 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    printValues(10, 20);
    printValues(30, "Hello");
    printValues(2.5, 7.5);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: check out function overloading

Comment: In C++20, [`void printValues( auto val1, auto val2 )`](https://godbolt.org/z/ernTTr9x9).  In any earlier version of C++, you can achieve the same with template parameters.

Comment: I want to do that without making multiple functions of same name (function overloading). I just need to write parameters for a single function. Any other way available?

Comment: how about: template <typename T1, typename T2> void printValues(T1 val1, T2 val2){cout << val1 << " " << val2 << endl;}

Comment: @DrewDormann this auto keyword really working cool. The solution using template is also looks good. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Note that whatever you print with `<<`  inside `printValues` still needs to be printable with `<<`. You may need to add `<<` a few overloads.

Comment: You want to do it without function overloading.   Technically, a templated function (like use of `auto` arguments, which is an alternative syntax to achieve the same thing) produces a family of overloaded functions.    The only difference is that the family members produced are determined by rules of template instantiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there is any way to do so without modifying the below code except the function parameters?

Yes, in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) using [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template), you might do

```
void printValues(auto val1, auto val2)
{
    std::cout << val1 << " " << val2 << std::endl;
}
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4xfnrP4ae)

---

Prior to that, you would need one additional line for making it a [template function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void printValues(T1 val1, T2 val2)
{
    std::cout << val1 << " " << val2 << std::endl;
}
```

[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/331q3v3v9)

Answer (score 3):

With `C++17` you can do the following using fold expressions

```
template<class... Types>
void print_args(Types&&... args)
{
    (std::cout << std::forward<decltype(args)>(args), ...);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a generalization of the question asked, so this will accept an arbitrary number of parameters, where the question only asks about two.

Comment: Also it's missing the space between printed arguments